# Why isn't elastic beanstalk restarting my unresponsive instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java spring application with a memory leak. I've actually resolved the cause of the memory leak (not properly closing jdbc connections), but I noticed that when my application became unresponsive, elastic beanstalk did not restart my instance and I had to do it manually. Why didn't it restart on its own?

[image: health overview]

As you can see, all of the requests are failing. From the aws [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html#using-features.healthstatus.understanding)

> If a health check URL is configured, Elastic Load Balancing expects a GET request that it sends to return a response of 200 OK. The application fails the health check if it fails to respond within 5 seconds or if it responds with any other HTTP status code. After 5 consecutive health check failures, Elastic Load Balancing takes the instance out of service.

I assumed that "takes the instance out of service" means that it terminates the instance and replaces it with a new one. Is this not the case? What's going on here?

Comment: Have you configured the health check URL in the Beanstalk environment configuration as per [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html) (see esp. Health Check section.)